# error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'mystring' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, smart-pointers

So i tried re-implementing my own string class using smart pointers just so I can practice integrating them into my daily use. Sadly, I've hit a wall, and I can't figure out why I'm unable to concatenate two "mystring" objects. Any suggestions? Also, if this type of program isn't the proper situation to use smart pointers in, I would also appreciate advice related to that as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class mystring {
public:
    mystring() : word(make_unique<char[]>('\0')), len(0) {}
    ~mystring() { cout << "goodbye objects!";}
    mystring(const char *message) : word(make_unique<char[]>(strlen(message) + 1)), len(strlen(message)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) word[i] = message[i];
    }
    mystring(const mystring &rhs) : word(make_unique<char[]>(rhs.len)), len(rhs.len + 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) word[i] = rhs.word[i];
    }
    mystring &operator=(mystring &rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            char *temp = word.release();
            delete[] temp;
            word = make_unique<char[]>(rhs.len + 1);
            len = rhs.len;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) word[i] = rhs.word[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }
    mystring &operator=(const char *rhs) {
        char *temp = word.release();
        delete[] temp;
        word = make_unique<char[]>(strlen(rhs)+ 1);
        len = strlen(rhs);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) word[i] = rhs[i];

        return *this;
    }
    friend mystring operator+(const mystring& lhs, const mystring& rhs) {
        mystring Result;
        int lhsLength = lhs.len, rhsLength = rhs.len;

        Result.word = make_unique<char[]>(lhsLength + rhsLength + 1);
        Result.len = lhsLength + rhsLength;
        for (int i = 0; i < lhsLength; i++) Result.word[i] = lhs.word[i];
        for (int i = lhsLength; i < lhsLength + rhsLength; i++) Result.word[i] = rhs.word[i];

        return Result;
    }
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, mystring &message) {
        for (int i = 0; i < message.len; i++) os << message.word[i];
        return os;
    }
private:
    int len;
    unique_ptr<char[]> word;
};

int main()
{
    mystring word1 = "Darien", word2 = "Miller", word3;

    cout << word1 + word2;//error message: no binary '<' found
    word3 = word1 + word2;//error message: no binary '=' found
    cout << word3;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably should set the final char to `'\0'` in all the places that build up the buffer.

Comment: That's a good idea actually. I'll do that right away

Answer (score 1):

Change the parameter `message`'s type of `operator<<` from `mystring &` (reference to non-const) to `const mystring &` (reference to const):

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const mystring &message) {
    for (int i = 0; i < message.len; i++) os << message.word[i];
    return os;
}
```

`operator+` returns by value, so what it returns is a temporary, which can't be bound to reference to non-const.

Note that you should do this not only for solving this issue; `message` shouldn't be passed by reference to non-const because the argument is not supposed to be modified inside `operator<<`.

Comment: Oh wow, Ok so adding in const to the parameter for both the operator << and operator = did in fact fix the issue! I'm curious though, why would omitting const in these two scenarios cause these errors to occur?

Comment: @DarienMiller because a non-const reference can't be bound to a temporary. google it.

Comment: @DarienMiller Binding reference to non-const to temporary is prohibitted and doesn't make sense. e.g. You can't write sth like `int& ri = 42 + 42;`.

Comment: @songyuanyao Copy. That makes perfect sense. So by changing the parameters to const, I'm no able to do operations like:

mystring word = "darien", word2 = "miller", word3;

cout << word + word2 or word3 = word + word2;

This actually creates a new problem where when I run the program (in VS), the program ends, due to a "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED" error message. Apparently, the destructor is throwing an exception. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DarienMiller I don't know; I suggest you debug `operator+` or `operator=`, you might find some unexpected behavior; or you can ask a new question with a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).